# How to specify encoding in .NET Interop.Excel.Workbooks.OpenText

Tags: c#, .net, excel, utf-8, interop

I'm not able to find any information about the possibility of specifying encoding (utf-8 in particular) when opening a text file with the excel.Workbooks.OpenText method. My problem is that I'm trying to open a CSV file that is encoded in UTF-8 and without this setting it loads as a bunch of squiggles.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: OK, I found out that Origin is the way to go, but setting it to 65001 (utf-8) does not work ...

Answer (score 2):

I found this as a working solution to import an UTF-8 csv file:
(it can be optimized a bit, but with this you can work in the right direction)

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbook wb;
Worksheet ws;
Range range;
int[,] a = new int[,] { { 1, 1 }, { 2, 2 }, { 3, 2 }, { 4, 2 }, { 5, 2 }, { 6, 2 }, { 7, 2 }, { 8, 2 }, { 9, 2 }, { 10, 2 }, { 11, 2 }, { 12, 2 }, { 13, 2 }, { 14, 2 }, { 15, 2 }, { 16, 2 }, { 17, 2 }, { 18, 2 }, { 19, 2 }, { 20, 2 }, { 21, 2 }, { 22, 2 } };
excelApp.Workbooks.OpenText(ofdGetExcel.FileName,
                                            65001,
                                            1,
                                            XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited,
                                            XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote,
                                            false,
                                            false,
                                            false,
                                            true,
                                            false,
                                            false,
                                            false,
                                            a,
                                            Type.Missing,//",",
                                            Type.Missing,//".",
                                            Type.Missing,//false,
                                            Type.Missing);//false);
wb = excelApp.ActiveWorkbook;
ws = wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
range = ws.get_Range("A2");

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.QueryTable QT = ws.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" + ofdGetExcel.FileName, range);
QT.Name = ofdGetExcel.FileName;
QT.FieldNames = true;
QT.RowNumbers = true;
QT.FillAdjacentFormulas = false;
QT.PreserveFormatting = true;
QT.RefreshOnFileOpen = false;
QT.RefreshStyle = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellInsertionMode.xlInsertDeleteCells;
QT.SavePassword = false;
QT.SaveData = true;
QT.AdjustColumnWidth = true;
QT.RefreshPeriod = 0;
QT.TextFilePromptOnRefresh = false;
QT.TextFilePlatform = 65001;
QT.TextFileStartRow = 1;
QT.TextFileParseType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited;
QT.TextFileTextQualifier = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote;
QT.TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = false;
QT.TextFileTabDelimiter = false;
QT.TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = false;
QT.TextFileCommaDelimiter = true;
QT.TextFileSpaceDelimiter = false;
QT.TextFileDecimalSeparator = ",";
QT.TextFileThousandsSeparator = ".";

ws.QueryTables[1].Destination.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

ws.QueryTables[1].Refresh(false);

ws.QueryTables[1].Delete();
```